# How to keep read and receive notifications of BLE in background?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-service

I have an application which allows to read and write (notify) in BLE. Following the sample example, I created my own read and write functions in the class `BluetoothLeService` as follows:

```
public void readCharacteristic() 
{
//My function
}
public void writeCustomCharacteristic(int value)
{
//My function
}
```

I want to keep read and write data when the application is in background. Hence, I must to make a service to do it. A simple structure of a service will be

```
public class backgroundservice extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

My question is how can I read/write data when my application is in background? If I use above service, which function do I need to use to call `readCharacteristic()` and `writeCustomCharacteristic(int value)`? For example, the `writeCustomCharacteristic(int value)` is called every 10 seconds. Thank all

Comment: onStartCommand this one

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct when I use service to keep read and write data of BLE when app is run in background?

Comment: discover your device services in OnCreate() method and then immediately call you readCharacteristic() and writeCustomCharacteristic (). Once your services are discovered read and write can happen even if the app is in the background.